# What is the use of calling context.write() in cleanup() of reducer

Tags: hadoop

Difference between executing context.write() in reduce() and in cleanup()?
I have read somewhere that cleanup will be called only after the output in temp_dir moves to output directory specified?

Also how to use treeMap in MR job with some example?

Comment: at the very least, `Also how to use treeMap in MR job with some example?` should be a different question / issue.

Comment: yes. i have a program in which treemap is declared in setup() and i need to find the word with max frequency. I have done this scenario in reduce() and trying to print the result through cleanup(). my MR job is running but ouptut shows oly the last word thats coming in the cleanup() loop.

Comment: But don't you think that should be a separate question on SO?

Answer (score 2):

a reducer task has following methods called like this:

```
run():
 setup()
 for each record:
    reduce()
 cleanup()
```

So as you can see setup() and cleanup() are called only once per reducer task while reduce() is called for each record (a record is a key and values).

In reducer you have only one key and its value at a time.
in cleanup, you can accumulate all the values (from each reducer) and do some processing and emit the output.

example:

```
reducer task:
  setup: create a map (hash or tree)
  for each reducer: store key, values in map 
  cleanup() : use the map and emit the key or values or both you are interested in.
```

caveat: if there is too much data to store in your internal structure (like treemap here), you may hit memory limitation of the machine where reduce task is running.

Comment: your answer gave me the best hint , i tried googling a lot and i even landed on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67085393/map-reduce-for-top-n-items where the accepted answer was talking about using multiple jobs and tree mapping when all i wanted was the highest count, your explanation to setup() and cleanup() was clear and beautiful. Can i get some source link to learn about mapper and reducer and context to do more things??????